# Row operations that show a matrix is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I’m looking at a bipartite graph with the following node-edge incidence matrix. The columns are labeled by the edges, and the two vertex partitions are $U = \{u1,u2\}$, and $V = \{v1,v2,v3\}$.

[image]

An argument says that summing up the rows for $U$ and subtracting the rows for $V$, we would get $\bf{0}$, hence the matrix is singular. What property of singular matrix is used here?

Answer (score 1):

The property used is that a matrix with linearly dependent rows is singular. In particular, if $R_k$ denotes the $k$th row of the given matrix $A$, then $R_1 + R_2 - R_3 - R_4 - R_5 = 0$, which means that $A$ is singular.

Equivalently, the non-zero row-vector $r = (1,1,-1,-1,-1)$ is such that $r A = 0$.